# How to extract the things from statement?

Tags: awk

My files example

```
peter,false,3117,2000,LOG,/home/peter,"BU : Econ Logistics<br />Customer Name : Yves Rocher <br />Create Date : 2019-02-26"
alan,false,3117,2000,TRA,/home/alan,"BU : Econ Trading<br />Customer Name : Alan Trade<br />Create Date : 2019-05-26"
toy,false,3117,2000,TRA,/home/toy,"Customer Name : TOY Trade <br />Create Date : 2019-05-26 <br /> BU : Econ Trading"
...etc..... over 10000 lines
```

I tried to obtain the output files like the following

```
peter,Econ Logistics
alan,Econ Trading
toy,Econ Trading
```

How can I get the output like to above??

```
cat AccountInfo.csv | cut -d ',' -f 1,7 | awk {print $1 $2}
```

but not working

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly recommended on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'/|,"|: |<br' -v OFS="," '
{
  match($0,/BU : [^<"]*/)
  print $3,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding only `match` function solution.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
match($0,/\/home\/[^,]*/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  match($0,/BU : [^<"]*/)
  print val1,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v OFS="," '                             ##Starting awk program from here and setting OFS as , here.
match($0,/\/home\/[^,]*/){                   ##Using match function to match regex /home/ till comma select everything here.
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)         ##Creating val1 with sub string of matched regex above.
  match($0,/BU : [^<"]*/)                    ##Using match to match regex to match text from BU : till < OR " everything.
  print val1,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)   ##Printing val1 and sub string of matched regex of previous used match function.
}
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: You could reduce that to just `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} match($0,/BU : [^<"]*/){print $1,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}'`.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E -n 's/^([[:alpha:]]+,).*(BU : )([[:alpha:] ]+).*/\1\3/p' file.txt
```

Explanation:

`-E` - use extended regex

`-n` - don't print anything to begin with

`^([[:alpha:]]+,)` - first group to capture (alphabetical characters up to and including the first comma)

`.*` - any characters between the first group and the second group

`(BU : )` - second group to capture

`([[:alpha:] ]+)` - third group to capture (any combination of letters and spaces, up to the next punctuation)

`.*` - any characters up until the end of the line

`\1\3/p'` - print the first capture group (the name and comma) then the third group (job description or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` can help:

```
awk -v FS=',|: |<|"' -v OFS=',' '!(NR%3) {print $1,$(NF-1);next}{print $1,$9}' file
peter,Econ Logistics
alan,Econ Trading
toy,Econ Trading
```

Tested in GNU `awk`.

- Updated. Ed Morton's code:

```
awk -v FS=',|: |<|"' -v OFS=',' '{print $1, (NR%3 ? $9 : $(NF-1))}' file    
peter,Econ Logistics
alan,Econ Trading                        
toy,Econ Trading
```

Thanks to Ed Morton.